# Sha1 - восстановление пароля

Tags: mysqli, php, sha1

У меня вновь проблемка) мне нужно чтобы пользователю на мыло отсылался правильный пароль, то есть не в зашифрованном виде sha1 а как он есть расшифрованный, у меня в базе зашифрованный пароль в sha1, как мне данное сделать?

Comment: Пароли нельзя передавать в открытом виде, никто не должен знать пароль пользователя, именно поэтому их солят и хешируют. Если вы делаете систему восстановления пароля, то попросите пользователя ввести новый пароль.

Comment: Хорошо, как мне реализовать что бы на почту приходила ссылка как бы тоже зашифрованная, когда пользователь открывал её там выводилась вот как раз таки поле для ввода нового пароля...

Comment: когда нужно отправить подобную ссылку, генерируйте случайную строку (к примеру md5 от текущего timestamp + соль). Эту строку отправляйте в url или как поле формы. А также эту строку записывайте в базу.Когда пользователь переходит по ссылке, можно всегда проверить по базе, что это валидная строка, восстановить эмейл и другие данные.